# understand the options of 'notify-send'

Tags: notify-send

I have gone through the man page for `notify-send` and I am not able to understand following two options

```
-u, --urgency=LEVEL Specifies the urgency level (low, normal, critical).
-h, --hint=TYPE:NAME:VALUE
          Specifies basic extra data to pass. Valid types are int, double, string and byte.
```

I believe the only use of urgency is to display a high urgency notification even if low urgency is in queue. 
But what are hints? I don't find any more info on it. Type I understand, but where will the NAME:VALUE be used?

Apart from above, the `-t` option says, "timeout in milliseconds", but I see notifications stay longer than given value. The given value is not even hounored. e.g I gave `-t 400`. The notification should be dismissed after 400 ms, but it goes after about 5 secs.

Any info on above posed questions?

Comment: [Hints are a way to provide extra data to a notification server](https://developer.gnome.org/notification-spec/#hints) that the server may be able to make use of so e.g. you could run : `notify-send -h string:sound-name:camera-shutter "HEY" "Message"`

Answer (score 6):

This is half-way at best, but perhaps you find some help in it.

---

There are two pieces to the puzzle *notify-send* and the *notify-daemon* or *notification-server*. Various implementations have various philosophies on what to include and how to use the different suggestions by [the spec](http://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/0.9/index.html).

Implementations like [NotifyOSD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD) supply an option on the `--expire-time` with `0` or default `-1`. If value is `0` and alert box is used instead of notification, any other value is ignored – and server default used.

The `--hint` option can be used to send extra information on how to lay out custom alerts such as volume and brightness. For example:

```
notify-send "Vol" -i notification-audio-volume-medium -h int:value:55 -h string:x-canonical-private-synchronous:volume
```

show a volume notification with level set to `55`.

As for the urgency level one thing, at least, is that it has an impact if other applications are running in full-screen mode. Games, video-player, (screen-saver?) etc. If Urgency level is *low* notifications are not displayed, if *critical* they are.

Comment: Example doesn't work any more (unless it's `Unity` specific, I use `Gnome`).

Comment: @CyprianGuerra: At time of answer I used Gnome as well. Not any GNOME desktop available at the moment, but works under Xfce, `notify-send 0.7.6` …